# Сайт загружается частично

Tags: дефект

Переодически (очень редко) сайт загружается в каком-то очень ограниченном виде:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Наблюдал такое только в Chrome на iPad пока что, но уже больше года с первого наблюдения.
Последующее обновление страницы проблему устраняет.

Comment: Возможно, это временный readony-режим, о котором недавно сообщалось на метамете?

Comment: @Qwertiy сомневаюсь. Описанная ситуация возникает куда чаще (хотя в целом и довольно редко), чем анонсированные периоды обслуживания сайтов сети.

Comment: @alexolut судя по значку - это оффлайновый режим мобильного хрома. случается, когда нет интернета, и когда в прошлый раз при отсутствии интернета была нажата кнопка вроде "скачать страницу". Тогда хром при подключении к инету скачивает что повезет, и показывает скачанное при следующем отсутствии интернета. Причем иногда хром достаточно настойчиво показывает скачанное даже если интернет есть. как-то так.

Comment: @alexolut вот подробнее об этой фиче: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/7343019?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en

Comment: @PashaPash сохранил страницу по-новому. Посмотрим, что будет в дальнейшем. Спасибо за подсказку.